# How to do this task without creating so many lists?

Tags: python, pandas

```py
import pandas as pd

#import data 
data = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\alek racicot\Downloads\TP4-Qualité (excel).xlsx")

titles = list(data.columns)
titles_value = []
echantillions = {}

#return sample mean of each column and add it to titles_value
for column in data:
    sample_mean = sum(data[column])/len(data[column])
    titles_value.append(sample_mean)

#take each element in titles as key and give it corresponding value
for i in range(len(titles)):
    echantillions[(titles[i])]= titles_value[i]

print(echantillions)
```

Comment: Can you post a small sample dataset?

Comment: Il n’y a qu’un seul « i » dans « échantillon » :)

Comment: @AlexanderCécile  je sais j'ai fais l'erreur et la paresse a fait le reste du travail :,)

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your dataset looks like, but it sounds like you're looking for pandas [mean](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html). Meaybe try this:

```
import pandas as pd

#import data 
data = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\alek racicot\Downloads\TP4-Qualité (excel).xlsx")
data = data.mean(axis=1)
print(data)
```

Comment: To get the specific dict the OP was asking about: `echantillions = { k: v for k, v in zip(data.columns, data.mean(axis=1)) }` instead of `data = data.mean(axis=1)` (which I also dislike because it is overwriting the data with the means, changing the meaning of the variable mid routine, but that's a style issue.